# power function in prolog

Tags: math, prolog, logic, exponentiation

What is wrong with my power function?

```
pow(_,0,1).   
pow(X,Y,Z) :-
    pow(X,Y-1,X*Z).

?- pow(2,3,Z).
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your Y does not get decremented, you can not use predicates like functions. You also have to unify Z with the result of the multiplication.

```
pow(_,0,1).

pow(X,Y,Z) :- Y1 is Y - 1,
              pow(X,Y1,Z1), Z is Z1*X.
```

There is also a builtin power function which will be much faster:

```
pow2(X,Y,Z) :- Z is X**Y.
```

Also note that pow is not a last call and can not be optimized to use only one stack frame. You should reformulate it to:

```
pow3(X,Y,Z) :- powend(X,Y,1,Z),!.

powend(_,0,A,Z) :- Z is A.
powend(X,Y,A,Z) :- Y1 is Y - 1, A1 is A*X, powend(X,Y1,A1,Z).
```

Comment: @ebo: Your definitions pow/3 and pow3/3 do not terminate! Try `pow(1,0,0)`. This should fail.

Comment: The Z parameter should not be bound. Also this is an academic example. Not all edge cases are considered to lower the complexity of the implementation.

Comment: Kind of strange, but fixed.

Comment: All three examples terminate in SWI-Prolog 5.10.4.

Comment: @ebo: They don't for `pow3(1,0,0)`

Answer (score 2):

```
Predicates
fac(Integer,Integer,Integer).
Clauses
fac(X,N,X):- N=1,!.
fac(X,N,M):- N1=N-1,fac(X,N1,M1), M= X*M1.
Goal
fac(5,3,X).
```

Comment: `fac(5,3,1)` should fail, but it loops.

Comment: in my case `fac(5,3,1)` return `no`, without loops, I use Visual_Prolog_v52_pe.

Comment: Impossible. You must have a different program.

Answer (score 1):

```
DOMAINS
num=INTEGER

PREDICATES
nondeterm power(num,num,num)

CLAUSES
power(X,0,1).
power(X,P,F):-X>0,P1=P-1,power(X,P1,F1),F=X*F1.

GOAL
power(2,5,X).
```